# popToRootViewControllerAnimated and Switch TabBar Index

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I am in the 3rd `UIViewController` of a `UINavigationController` and would like to dismiss all `UIViewController`s before switching tabs on the `UITabBarController` that contains my `UINavigationController`.

```
    self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
    self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 1
```

The code above does not switch tab bar indexes. It seems that code after `popToRootViewControllerAnimated` never runs.

What are my options?

Comment: Are you sure `self.tabBarController` is not `nil`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no API to provide a completion block to `popToRootViewControllerAnimated` and I'm guessing that once you pop the VC, it's gone and no more code executes.  It's like you want to provide a completion block to be performed once the animation completes.

The `UINavigationController` API itself doesn't offer any options for this.

However by using a combination of CoreAnimation framework and NSNotifications it's possible to add a completion block that posts a notification, which the root view controller can listen for.

You might even be able to get away without the CoreAnimation trickery, and just post the notification after you `popToRootViewControllerAnimated` but I haven't tried that yet.

This would be the code for the bottom view controller in the stack:

```
class DetailViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBAction func popAndSwitchTabs(sender: AnyObject) {
        CATransaction.begin()
        CATransaction.setCompletionBlock { () -> Void in
            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("switchTabsNotification", object: nil)
        }
        self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
        CATransaction.commit()
    }

}
```

And then use code like this in the top view controller in the stack:

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "switchTabs", name: "switchTabsNotification", object: nil)
    }

    func switchTabs() {
        self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 1
    }

}
```

Here's a quick example project I threw together that you can try out on Github:
https://github.com/obuseme/PopAndSwitchExample

Comment: Clever solution! thanks. Will wait a bit to see other answers before accepting yours.